# XSLT 1.0 Kludge cleanup

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am printing a line in reverse font (black background, white text), spread over the width of my receipt tape (41 characters).  I have functional code, but I am wondering if there is a better way to do this:

Here's my existing code:

```
<text lang="en" align="center" smooth="true" reverse="1"><xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces21, 1, (string-length($spaces21) - ((string-length(SavingsSegment) div 2) + string-length(SavingsSegment) mod 2)))"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="SavingsSegment"/><xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces21, 1, (string-length($spaces21) - ((string-length(SavingsSegment) div 2) + string-length(SavingsSegment) mod 2)))"/>
</text>
```

This code results in this XML:

```
 <text lang="en" align="center" smooth="true" reverse="1" xmlns="">             YOU SAVED $2.00             </text>
```

Clarification: spaces21 is a text field with 21 spaces in it, if that wasn't already obvious.

The xml prints correctly, no matter the value I put in ($1,275,824.00 worked just as well as $2.00).

My problem is that this is the kludgiest kludge that ever did kludge.  Is there a way to do this in a cleaner manner?

Thanks!

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I guess an XSLT-1.0 one, because of the tag. If it's version 1.0 your solution  is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: @zx485 I noticed the tag. But some XSLT 1.0 processors support extensions.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Visual Studio 2017, which doesn't support above XSLT-1.0.

Comment: But if I'm not mistaken, it supports dipping into other languages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script

Comment: @michael.hor257k yep, it does.  And our senior developer doesn't want to do that.  He wants vanilla VS2017 with no add-ons.  I just do what I'm told.

Comment: Can't say I blame him. But the option is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `libxslt` or `Xalan` or another processor that supports the EXSLT [str:align()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/align/index.html) and [str:padding()](http://exslt.org/str/functions/padding/index.html) extension functions, then you could do simply:

```
<text>
    <xsl:value-of select="str:align(SavingsSegment, str:padding(41, ' '), 'center')"/>
</text>
```

---

To do it in pure XSLT 1.0, I believe this would be more elegant:

```
<xsl:variable name="spaces21" select="'                     '"/>
<xsl:variable name="pad" select="(41 - string-length(SavingsSegment)) div 2"/>
<text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces21, 1, floor($pad))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="SavingsSegment"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($spaces21, 1, ceiling($pad))"/>
</text>
```

Comment: That's perfect.  It's definitely prettier, at least.  :-)  Thanks!